# How to extract multiple rows of data relative to single row in scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I am trying to scrape webpage given in the this link -
http://new-york.eat24hours.com/picasso-pizza/19053

Here I am trying to get all the possible details like address and phone etc..
So, Far I have extracted the name, phone, address, reviews, rating.
But I also want to extract the the full menu of restaurant here(name of item with price).
So, far I have no idea how to manage this data into output of csv.

The rest of the data for a single url will be single but the items in menu will always be of different amount.

here below is my code so far-

```
import scrapy
from urls import start_urls

class eat24Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
    name = 'eat24'

    def start_requests(self):
        for x in start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(x, self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):

        brickset = response
        NAME_SELECTOR = 'normalize-space(.//h1[@id="restaurant_name"]/a/text())'
        ADDRESS_SELECTION = 'normalize-space(.//span[@itemprop="streetAddress"]/text())'
        LOCALITY = 'normalize-space(.//span[@itemprop="addressLocality"]/text())'
        REGION = 'normalize-space(.//span[@itemprop="addressRegion"]/text())'
        ZIP = 'normalize-space(.//span[@itemprop="postalCode"]/text())'
        PHONE_SELECTOR = 'normalize-space(.//span[@itemprop="telephone"]/text())'
        RATING = './/meta[@itemprop="ratingValue"]/@content'
        NO_OF_REVIEWS = './/meta[@itemprop="reviewCount"]/@content'
        OPENING_HOURS = './/div[@class="hours_info"]//nobr/text()'
        EMAIL_SELECTOR = './/div[@class="company-info__block"]/div[@class="business-buttons"]/a[span]/@href[substring-after(.,"mailto:")]'

        yield {
            'name': brickset.xpath(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first().encode('utf8'),
            'pagelink': response.url,
            'address' : str(brickset.xpath(ADDRESS_SELECTION).extract_first().encode('utf8')+', '+brickset.xpath(LOCALITY).extract_first().encode('utf8')+', '+brickset.xpath(REGION).extract_first().encode('utf8')+', '+brickset.xpath(ZIP).extract_first().encode('utf8')),
            'phone' : str(brickset.xpath(PHONE_SELECTOR).extract_first()),
            'reviews' : str(brickset.xpath(NO_OF_REVIEWS).extract_first()),
            'rating' : str(brickset.xpath(RATING).extract_first()),
            'opening_hours' : str(brickset.xpath(OPENING_HOURS).extract_first())
        }
```

I am sorry if I am making this confusing but any kind of help will be appreciated. 
Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract full restaurant menu, first of all, you need to locate element who contains both name and price:

```
menu_items = response.xpath('//tr[@itemscope]')
```

After that, you can simply make for loop and iterate over restaurant items appending name and price to list:

```
menu = []
for item in menu_items:
    menu.append({
        'name': item.xpath('.//a[@class="cpa"]/text()').extract_first(),
        'price': item.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="price"]/text()').extract_first()
        })
```

Finally you can add new 'menu' key to your  dict:

```
yield {'menu': menu}
```

Also, I suggest you use scrapy Items for storing scraped data:
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html

For outputting data in csv file use scrapy Feed exports, type in console:

```
scrapy crawl yourspidername -o restaurants.csv
```